# Clear all the GPU memory used by pytorch in current python code without exiting python

Tags: python, memory-management, pytorch, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am running a modified version of a third-party code which uses pytorch and GPU. I run the same model multiple times by varying the configs, which I am doing within python i.e. I have a wrapper python file which calls the model with different configs. But I am getting `out-of-memory` errors while running the second or third model. That is to say, the model can run once properly without any memory issues. So, if I end the code after running the first model and then start the second model afresh, the code works fine. However, if I chain the models within python, I'm running into `out-of-memory` issues.

I suspect there are some memory leaks within the third-party code. On googling, I found two suggestions. One is to call `torch.cuda.empty_cache()`, and the other is to delete the tensors explicitly using `del tensor_name`. However, `empty_cache()` command isn't helping free the entire memory, and the third-party code has too many tensors for me to delete all the tensors individually. Is there any way to clear the entire GPU memory used by the current python program within the python code itself?

Comment: You could try multiprocessing. Create a model iteration in a child process, return the results to the parent, kill the child (which frees all GPU memory used by the child), then start the next iteration. The current answer does not always work, especially when doing things like k-fold cross validation or federated learning.

Comment: Thanks. I could try that. Why do you say that it doesn't work for K-fold cross validation?

Comment: K-fold cross validation usually can either happen by creating the model outside the k-fold loop, which would mean after each iteration, you have to reset the weights, which makes the current answer irrelevant. If you make the model within the k-fold loop, the gc won't clear the model because the reference count (forgot the actual name) is not 0, so gc won't remove it.

Comment: If you need a barebones example of how to do it, I can submit it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. 1: I understand the problem with creating the model outside `k-fold` loop, but I don't understand what the problem is if we create the model inside the `k-fold` loop. Within the `k-fold` loop, if I call another function which creates the model and performs validation, after returning from the function, the reference count (within the `k-fold` loop) should be zero, right? Or did you mean the case where we create the model within the loop without using another function? 2: It will help me and others as well, if you can give an example.

Comment: If you create the model within the loop, after the loop, you will be creating a new instance of the model that isn't removing the previously created model, from my experience.

Comment: I've submitted an answer using multiprocessing.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to determine what is causing the memory issue without actually reading the code. But most of the time when `empty_cache()` can't finish the cleaning is because of some process still running.
So, try adding this after `empty_cache()`

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Garbage collector and `del` directly on the model and training data rarely worked for me when using a model that's within a loop. Usually, each iteration creates a new model without clearing the previous model from memory, making it so the entire loop requires `(model_size + training data) * n` amount of memory capacity, where *n* is the number of iterations. This is also a problem when using federated learning tools such as [Flower](https://flower.dev/) or when using k-fold cross validation. If you want to use a multiprocessing approach which should always work to clear GPU memory used by the child process, this will work:

```python
import torch
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


class nn_model(torch.nn.Module)
   # define class for model


def train_fn(model, train_ds, val_ds, queue)
    # do training stuff
    history = # save training metrics into history dictionary

    queue.put(model, history)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_ds = # load train dataset
    val_ds = # load val dataset
    test_ds = # load test dataset

    model = nn_model(*args)

    pool = Pool(1)  # or replace 1 with however many child processes you want
    queue = Manager().Queue()

    # assume training loop of three iterations
    [pool.apply_async(train_fn, args=(model, train_ds, val_ds, queue)) for _ in range(3)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    # this next line will give a variable queue_results containing a tuple of (model, history)
    queue_results = [queue.get() for _ in range(queue.qsize())]

    # assuming queue_results contains only one element
    model, history = queue_results[0]
    
    for i, j in test_ds:
        with torch.no_grad():
            model = model.eval()
            preds = model(i)
```

If you don't want to use Pool and want to explicitly kill the child process, you can use (instead of Pool):

```python
from torch.multiprocessing import Process


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ...

    # inside "_main__" replacing Pool, assuming three iterations
    procs = [mp.Process(target=train_fn, args=(model, train_ds, val_ds, queue)) for _ in range(3)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
        p.join()
    
    queue_results = [queue.get() for _ in range(queue.qsize())]

    for p in procs:
        try:
            p.close()
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f"Couldn't close process: {e}")
        del p

    # assuming queue_results contains only one element
    model, history = queue_results[0]
    
    for i, j in test_ds:
        with torch.no_grad():
            model = model.eval()
            preds = model(i)
```

I think using Pool is more convenient than Process.

Comment: Thanks @Djinn. Yes, I think `Pool` is more convenient.